# Splitting large Rails controller without adding new models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

What is the best way to split up a large Rails controller, that is large due to logic (for example a checkout with logic for multiple providers)?

The goal is just to have several files instead of one, without having to add new models

Comment: You could refactor the "checkout logic for multiple providers" out into a collection of services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no universal way would describe how to organize the code. How to split it is an individual decision.
But I can give some common recommendation. I have dealt with stuff like this and can imagine what you have there. So you might find them useful:

- try with small changes
- find duplicated code and extract it to methods defined in this
  controller first
- later you can decide what to do with them, but small changes like that help you to grasp the whole picture
- simplify code if it's possible
- try to figure out responsibilities of the controller, specifically its actions,  that's the final goal
- once you clearly understand responsibilities of the code you can start to think how to split it
- the split should be made based on responsibility of the code chunks
- you can use patterns like form objects, service objects, etc.

Comment: Thank you. And specifically would that be better to use namespaces / scopes? I am assuming Concerns are best for the reusable code (although they do work for this case as well, technicall).

Comment: Sometimes concerns would be a good choice. But if you want not to have method names collision and have your classes' interfaces clean and tiny, it's better to avoid concerns and prefer composition - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: In other words, concerns bloat classes interface, that's eventually doesn't solve any problem from architectural point of view, because you still have the same set of classes and their interfaces are not changed.